multiple definition linker error while compiling project with 'mksquashfs'
I'm encountering a 'multiple definition' error while trying to compile a project that includes "mksquashfs". The error I'm getting are like this:
/usr/bin/ld: read_fs.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `fwriter_buffer'; mksquashfs.o:(.bss+0x400c90): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: read_fs.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `bwriter_buffer'; mksquashfs.o:(.bss+0x400c98): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: action.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `fwriter_buffer'; mksquashfs.o:(.bss+0x400c90): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: action.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `bwriter_buffer'; mksquashfs.o:(.bss+0x400c98): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: sort.o:(.bss+0x100000): multiple definition of `fwriter_buffer'; mksquashfs.o:(.bss+0x400c90): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: sort.o:(.bss+0x100008): multiple definition of `bwriter_buffer'; mksquashfs.o:(.bss+0x400c98): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: info.o:(.bss+0x10): multiple definition of `bwriter_buffer'; mksquashfs.o:(.bss+0x400c98): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: info.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `fwriter_buffer'; mksquashfs.o:(.bss+0x400c90): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: restore.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `fwriter_buffer'; mksquashfs.o:(.bss+0x400c90): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: restore.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `bwriter_buffer'; mksquashfs.o:(.bss+0x400c98): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: process_fragments.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `fwriter_buffer'; mksquashfs.o:(.bss+0x400c90): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: process_fragments.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `bwriter_buffer'; mksquashfs.o:(.bss+0x400c98): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: xattr.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `fwriter_buffer'; mksquashfs.o:(.bss+0x400c90): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: xattr.o:(.bss+0x10): multiple definition of `bwriter_buffer'; mksquashfs.o:(.bss+0x400c98): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [Makefile:284: mksquashfs] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

It seems like multiple object files are defining the same variable, specifically "fwriter_buffer" and "bwriter_buffer". The error suggest that these variables are defined in "mksquashfs.o" and other object files like "read_fs.o", "action.o", etc.
How can I resolve this "multiple definition" linker error?
Is there a best practice to avoid such conflict ?
Additional Information:

I'm compiling this on a Linux system using "riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc (version: 13.2.0)"
The project uses "make" for the build process


999 times out of 1000 this means you've defined these variables in a header file that is then included in all the source files.  Instead, you should declare the variables in the header file (for example, by using extern) and define them in one of the source files.
